# Novel Series ID: really thin books

Tags: story-identification

I have a really poor ID question, but this mental block is killing me (figuratively, of course).

I read the series at least 50 years ago, and I think the series is actually from the Golden Age of Science Fiction, or even earlier, perhaps early pulp magazines.

It is/was a series of novels/novelettes. I say that because, physically, I remember the books themselves were VERY thin.

They were all about the adventures of a (military, or militaristic) crew, who travelled to worlds of a space empire, solving issues, crimes, invasions, etc. The leader, I think, had a rank, and was known by that, such as Captain, or Commander, or something.

The same crew was in multiple novels and some of them were interconnected, I think.

I think there were at least 100 novelettes, but perhaps even more.

(Yes, I know there is almost no information here, but my google-foo has completely deserted me.)

Comment: [Perry Rhodan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perry_Rhodan)?

Comment: I agree with John Rennie; if there are that many books it pretty much has to be Perry Rhodan.  Even Bulmer's *Dray Prescott* only reached into the 50s, and that's more than *Conan* or *Gor*.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm going to speculate these are the [Perry Rhodan books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perry_Rhodan), if only because it's the only series I can think of with hundreds (literally) of slim books.

Perry is a Major in the US Space Force, which may be the title you remember.

Comment: While Perry Rhodan, starting in 1961, really can't be counted as Golden Age, the *feel* of the series is very pulpy, so a good guess. If not for the length of the series, I would have suggested E.E. "Doc" Smith's *Lensman* books, which are truly Golden Age, but that series has only a handful of thin books. If not for the crew and rank details, E.C. Tubbs' *Dumarest* books could have been another good guess.

Comment: Wait, so the US Space Force was invented by a German pulp fiction franchise?  Or was it a German space force in the original books, and they just changed it for the US audience?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I can't comment, though when I read the first few books I didn't even realise they were German. Whatever publisher produced the English editions did not make that clear.

Comment: Perry Rhodan, that's it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It could be Commander John Grimes, there are a lot of relatively short stories by A. Bertram Chandler and they fit your description.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._Bertram_Chandler#John_Grimes_novels

Comment: Could you elaborate on how precisely those stories fit the description given in the question, and any ways in which they don't fit, if there are any?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  It just so happens I've been rereading these, and after the first few books Grimes is largely on his own with a rotating cast and no consistent crew.  There also aren't nearly enough (23) of these.